# $ L_1(\mathbb R)$is not algebra with pointwise product

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that $f, g \in L_1(\mathbb R)$ does not imply $fg \in L_1(\mathbb R)$

I've found several examples of functions which are closed under  multiplication on an interval but I can't come up with $\mathbb R$

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just define your example functions to be zero outside the interval?

Comment: Something like $f = g = 1/\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1)$, and zero elsewhere, should work

Comment: Bungo, thank you